# amsmath\enumitem\solutionbox: How to decrease vertical spacing within solution box

Tags: amsmath, enumitem, line-spacing

Within the **solution box**, I'm using `\bigskip` to create **horizontal space between each line of the step-by-step solution** as a means of facilitating readability.

But the spacing seems a bit excessive:

[image]

Additionally, even with autofill, repeatedly typing `\bigskip` doesn't seem particularly efficient.

So 2 questions:

1. Is redefining `\bigskip` the best way to reduce the spacing (just for the math steps inside the solution box)?
2. Is there any way to automate the spacing to avoid typing `\bigskip` after every line?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{exam}
\printanswers
% un-comment to print solutions.
\renewcommand{\solutiontitle}{}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[nice]{nicefrac}
\usepackage{tasks}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=0.5in,include head]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{soul}
\pagestyle{head}
\header{Algebra II: Unit 13 A\&B Fractional Exponents}
       {}
       {Due 05/02/23} 

\newcommand{\pagetop}{%
%\noindent 
\bigskip
  \vspace{0.5mm}
}
\newlength{\lwidth}% added <<<<<
\settowidth{\lwidth}{(99)\enspace} % added

\settasks{after-item-skip=1em,
    after-skip=2cm,
    label-width=\lwidth, % changed <<<<<<<<<
    item-indent=0pt,   % changed <<<<<<<<<<
    %label-format = \bfseries, 
    %add \bf to make numbers bold <<<<<<<<<<
    label=(\arabic*), % 
    label-offset = -\lwidth,% added <<<<<
    item-format = \hspace{\lwidth},% added <<<<<
    column-sep=2em,    % changed <<<<<<<<<  
}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\fullwidth}[1]{%
    \vbox{%     
        \leftskip=-\lwidth \rightskip=0pt
        \advance\linewidth\@totalleftmargin%
        \@totalleftmargin=0pt%
        #1}%
    \nobreak
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
%definition for bigskip = 1 line to replace all \bigskip
\def\bigskip{\vskip\bigskipamount}
\begin{tasks}
[style=enumerate](3)
\task![]\fullwidth{\textbf{Change to radicals.}}
%%%% Prob #15
\task $(a^3b^5)^{1/6}$
\begin{solutionorbox}[5cm]
$(a^{3\bm{\cdot}1/6})(b^{5\bm{\cdot}1/6})$
\bigskip
$(a^{1/2})(b^{5/6})$
\bigskip
%>>>>adding \vphantom causes bot radicals to be same height
\colorbox{yellow}{$\sqrt{\vphantom{b}a}\sqrt[6]{b^5}$  or $\sqrt[6]{a^3b^5}$}
\end{solutionorbox}
\vspace{0.25cm}
%%
%%%% Prob #16
\task
$(a^7b^3)^{1/8}$
\begin{solutionorbox}[5cm]
$(a^{7\bm{\cdot}1/8})(b^{3\bm{\cdot}1/8})$
\bigskip
$(a^{7/8})(b^{3/8})$
\bigskip
%>>>>adding \vphantom causes bot radicals to be same height
\colorbox{yellow}{$\sqrt[8]{a^7b^3}$}
\end{solutionorbox}
\vspace{0.25cm}
%%
\newpage
\task![]\fullwidth{\textbf{Simplify. (Add exponents)}}
%% Prob #17
\task
$x^{3/4}\bm{\cdot}x^{1/4}$
\begin{solutionorbox}[5cm]
$x^{3/4+1/4}$
\bigskip
\colorbox{yellow}{$x^{4/4}=x$}
\end{solutionorbox}
%% Prob #18
\task
$a^{1/2}\bm{\cdot}a^{2/3}$
\begin{solutionorbox}[5cm]
$x^{1/2+2/3}$
\bigskip
\colorbox{yellow}{$x^{3/6+4/6}=x^{7/6}$}
\end{solutionorbox}
%% Prob #19
\task
$b^{3/4}\bm{\cdot}b^{1/10}$
\begin{solutionorbox}[5cm]
$b^{3/4+1/10}$
\bigskip
\colorbox{yellow}{$b^{15/20+2/20}=x^{17/20}$}
\end{solutionorbox}
%% Prob #20
\task
$5^{1/4}\bm{\cdot}5^{3/4}$
\begin{solutionorbox}[5cm]
$5^{1/4+3/4}$
\bigskip
\colorbox{yellow}{$5^{4/4}=5$}
\end{solutionorbox}
%% Prob #21
\task
$8^{1/3}\bm{\cdot}8^{1/4}$
\begin{solutionorbox}[5cm]
$8^{1/3+1/4}$
\bigskip
\colorbox{yellow}{$8^{4/12+3/12}=x^{7/12}$}
\end{solutionorbox}
%% Prob #22
\task
$z^{3/4}\bm{\cdot}z^{1/2}\bm{\cdot}z$
\begin{solutionorbox}[5cm]
$z^{3/4+1/2+1}$
\bigskip
\colorbox{yellow}{$z^{3/4+2/4+4/4}=x^{9/4}$}
\end{solutionorbox}
\task![]\fullwidth{\textbf{Simplify.(Subtract exponents)}}
%% Prob #23
\task
$\dfrac{a^{3/4}b^{1/10}}{a^{1/4}b^{1/20}}$
\vspace{0.25cm}
\begin{solutionorbox}[5cm]
$a^{(3/4-1/4)}b^{(1/10-1/20)}$
\bigskip
\colorbox{yellow}{$a^{(2/4)}b^{(1/20)}=a^{1/2}b^{1/20}$}
\end{solutionorbox}
%% Prob #24
\task
$\dfrac{a^{3/4}b}{a^{1/6}b^{1/3}}$
\vspace{0.25cm}
\begin{solutionorbox}[5cm]
$a^{(3/4-1/6)}b^{(1-1/3)}$
\bigskip
\colorbox{yellow}{$a^{(2/4)}b^{(1/20)}=a^{1/2}b^{1/20}$}
\end{solutionorbox}

\end{tasks}
\end{document}
```

Comment: 1) It shouldn't be necessary to define `\bigskip`; it should be there by default.  2) Two other vertical skips should already be present: `\medskip` and `\smallskip`.  One of those might be more appropriate.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Thanks very much for your response. When I replaced ```\bigskip``` (which creates the desired line break) with either ```\medskip``` or ```\smallskip```, no line break results. But if I preface either command with ```\\```, the line break occurs with the appropriate spacing. Why is placement of  ```\\``` **before** the ```\skip``` required for a line break? Thanks again!

Comment: Ah.  I should have noticed that these were in horizontal mode.  The vertical skips are best issued in vertical mode, that is, after a paragraph break.  A double backslash *isn't* the way to end a paragraph, but it does make the current line end, and that's essential.